# Can Elastic search reject request if a bulk request contains same document twice with different properties?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am learning Elastic Search, so forgive me for this starter question.

The scenario is that we have multiple data producer that would send the data to AWS Kinesis firehose which is configured to deliver it to AWS Elastic search.
It is possible that same data is posted to Kinesis firehose by multiple data producers based on different edits happening.

Since the Kinesis Firehose buffers the request and then delivers in bulk to ES, there is a possibility that the bulk request would have multiple edits of the same document.

How do I ensure that only latest document is processed?

As a note, all documents have a timestamp field that denote the last modified time for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this in case if someone in future finds this useful.

I came across this feature in elastic search on [versioning](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-index_.html#index-versioning). This somehow provides me an ability to control the indexing to some extent. 
Also another thread on elastic search forum [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/conditional-insert-of-data-in-es/13486) talks about the same thing using own version numbering to prevent out of order writes.
I played with version_type=external and own versioning scheme which so far seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

No. Elasticsearch doesn't have an option to validate the document duplication. Still, you can achieve this in many other ways. Refer below links for more details

https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-documents-in-elasticsearch

https://www.elastic.co/blog/efficient-duplicate-prevention-for-event-based-data-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sharing the link. One of the suggestion to not auto-generate the id is something we are already following as we generate our own unique Id. However, it is a possibility that one or more producers may pick up the same document from source in a race condition scenario and may cause an older as well as newer documents both getting sent to Kinesis and Then to ES.